# pass 2 variables in php android

Tags: php, android, post

Good day,
I have a php code that has a $_POST['Query'] function, i want to add it with $_POST['Tags'] but how can I pass 2 variables in android using to php, I had pass the a value to a $_POST['Query'] with my code but how can I pass the second one ?

```
OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("Query", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(query,"UTF-8");
        bw.write(data);
        bw.flush();

        con.connect();

        bw.close();
        os.close();
```

Comment: It seems to be related to php question. So, removed java tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply append another parameter with `&`

```
String data = URLEncoder.encode("Query", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(query,"UTF-8");
       data+= "&"+URLEncoder.encode("Tags", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(yourTags,"UTF-8");
```

Note : For efficiency use `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder params = new StringBuilder();
params.append(URLEncoder.encode("Query", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(query,"UTF-8"));
params.append("&");
params.append(URLEncoder.encode("Tags", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(yourTagStr,"UTF-8"));
bw.write(params.toString());
// ... code
```

Comment: i am glad that i could help and for next level you can also look into some network libraries like [`Volley`](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) (simple) and `retrofit` (more efficient and dynamic with bit more efforts )